# DNS -- why is my application getting a "no such name" response when other applications do not from the same server?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm writing a tiny DNS client and it's sending the following query to `8.8.8.8` for `google.com`:

```
1337    10.324082781    192.168.0.10    8.8.8.8 DNS 70  Standard query 0xa689 A google.com

0000   60 2a d0 90 25 1f e0 69 95 c6 de 71 08 00 45 00  `*..%..i...q..E.
0010   00 38 8f 83 40 00 40 11 da 6f c0 a8 00 0a 08 08  .8..@.@..o......
0020   08 08 e9 59 00 35 00 24 86 e7 a6 89 01 00 00 01  ...Y.5.$........
0030   00 00 00 00 00 00 0a 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 2e 63 6f  .......google.co
0040   6d 00 00 01 00 01                                m.....
```

According to wireshark, this query isn't malformed, and it correctly contains all of the fields necessary for a DNS standard query for an `A` record with the name `google.com`. However, I get a strange response from the DNS server:

```
1338    10.346529886    8.8.8.8 192.168.0.10    DNS 145 Standard query response 0xa689 No such name A google.com SOA a.root-servers.net

0000   e0 69 95 c6 de 71 60 2a d0 90 25 1f 08 00 45 00  .i...q`*..%...E.
0010   00 83 3e 2d 00 00 3b 11 70 7b 08 08 08 08 c0 a8  ..>-..;.p{......
0020   00 0a 00 35 e9 59 00 6f ac 0f a6 89 81 83 00 01  ...5.Y.o........
0030   00 00 00 01 00 00 0a 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 2e 63 6f  .......google.co
0040   6d 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 06 00 01 00 00 07 03 00  m...............
0050   40 01 61 0c 72 6f 6f 74 2d 73 65 72 76 65 72 73  @.a.root-servers
0060   03 6e 65 74 00 05 6e 73 74 6c 64 0c 76 65 72 69  .net..nstld.veri
0070   73 69 67 6e 2d 67 72 73 03 63 6f 6d 00 78 2a d2  sign-grs.com.x*.
0080   09 00 00 07 08 00 00 03 84 00 09 3a 80 00 01 51  ...........:...Q
0090   80                                               .
```

This is a standard response with an error, "no such name google.com", and it also provides an SOA response. This is strange, because shortly after this I went into Firefox and navigated to `google.com`, listened for the outgoing DNS query packet with Wireshark:

```
2283    17.628229748    192.168.0.10    8.8.8.8 DNS 70  Standard query 0x7257 A google.com

0000   60 2a d0 90 25 1f e0 69 95 c6 de 71 08 00 45 00  `*..%..i...q..E.
0010   00 38 90 73 40 00 40 11 d9 7f c0 a8 00 0a 08 08  .8.s@.@.........
0020   08 08 f7 14 00 35 00 24 b1 89 72 57 01 00 00 01  .....5.$..rW....
0030   00 00 00 00 00 00 06 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 03 63 6f  .......google.co
0040   6d 00 00 01 00 01                                m.....
```

and received a proper response with the contents for the `A` record for `google.com`:

```
2285    17.649603341    8.8.8.8 192.168.0.10    DNS 86  Standard query response 0x7257 A google.com A 172.217.3.174

0000   e0 69 95 c6 de 71 60 2a d0 90 25 1f 08 00 45 00  .i...q`*..%...E.
0010   00 48 6f d9 00 00 3b 11 3f 0a 08 08 08 08 c0 a8  .Ho...;.?.......
0020   00 0a 00 35 f7 14 00 34 bf 87 72 57 81 80 00 01  ...5...4..rW....
0030   00 01 00 00 00 00 06 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 03 63 6f  .......google.co
0040   6d 00 00 01 00 01 c0 0c 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 c6  m...............
0050   00 04 ac d9 03 ae                                ......
```

What could be possibly be causing this? Both applications are sending well-formed DNS queries to the same server and yet are receiving different responses.

Comment: I don't read binary but I can easily see some differences between your query and Firefox's, which I assume is likely responsible.  Look at the 3rd line of your hex dump for the queries.

Comment: Note that the query and response you show from Firefox are identical, which is likely a copy error.

Comment: Oops! will edit.

Comment: I can't figure out a case when it would be useful to write your own DNS resolver instead of using the libraries present in practically every OS...

Answer (score 2):

Your formatting of the domain name in your query seems to be incorrect, according to http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DNSNameNotationandMessageCompressionTechnique.htm

The DNS protocol does not use dots (ASCII 2E) to delineate portions of a domain name...rather it uses length. In your second query, notice that "google" is preceded by ASCII 06, and "com" is preceded by ASCII 03. You seem to have calculated the length of "google.com" as ASCII 0A, and prepended.